# .pyw equivalent for node.js scripts

Tags: python, node.js

If you change extension of python script from `.py` to `.pyw` it'll be executed silently (without bringing up cmd).

Is there something similar for `.js` / `.mjs` files?

Comment: it exists only in Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not Node specific, but how about using [vbs](https://superuser.com/questions/140047/how-to-run-a-batch-file-without-launching-a-command-window) to launch a windowless cmd?

Or maybe some of [these](https://superuser.com/questions/191149/how-to-execute-cmd-exe-silently) options.